# Django - Need some assistance with Refactoring / Improving my view

Tags: python, django, view, refactoring

Im making an airbnb website as a project, and I have created this monster ( yes, I know ) :

```py
def apartment_view(request, apartment_id):

    reservation = Reservation.objects.filter(apartment__pk=apartment_id)
    apartment = get_object_or_404(Apartment, pk=apartment_id)
    context = {}
    context['apartment'] = apartment

    unavailable = []
    for start, end in apartment.reservations.values_list('start_date', 'end_date'):
        while start <= end:
            unavailable.append(start.strftime('%-d-%m-%Y'))
            start += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    form = ReservationForm()
    context['unavailable_dates'] = json.dumps(unavailable)
    context['form'] = form

    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ReservationForm()
        if request.method == "GET":
             form = ReservationForm(request.GET)
             if form.is_valid():
                context = {}
                reservation = form.save(commit=False)
                reservation.apartment = apartment                      
                start_date = request.GET.get('start_date', None)
                end_date = request.GET.get('end_date', None)
                sdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d') #start
                edate = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date ,'%Y-%m-%d') #end
                prices_by_date = apartment.price_by_date(sdate, edate)
                user_dates = [sdate + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range((edate-sdate).days + 1)]
                user_date_list = []
                for day in user_dates:
                    user_date_list.append(day.strftime('%d,%m,%Y'))

                context['price_per_day'] = prices_by_date.price
                context['total_price'] =  len(user_date_list) * prices_by_date.price    
                context['unavailable_dates'] = json.dumps(unavailable)
                context['form'] = form
                context['apartment'] = apartment           
                context['date_start'] = start_date
                context['date_end'] = end_date 
                form.save()
                return render(request, "booking/apartment.html", context)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReservationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():            
            reservation = form.save(commit=False)
            reservation.apartment = apartment
            reservation.save()        
            form.save()
            HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('booking:apartment', kwargs={"apartment_id": apartment.pk}))

    return render(request, 'booking/apartment.html', context)
```

To describe what is going on, user first comes to the site and picks the start and end date to book the apartment. They press the button to calculate the total price of the reservation, the page gets refreshed and displays the prices.
Then they click on a "confirm reservation" button which makes a post request with the reservation, the page is refreshed once again, and now displays the "Thank you for your reservation" text.

Is there any way I could improve this view ? I pretty much did what I could, I'm still learning django. I should maybe change it to a class based view, but got no clue how to do that, it's pretty confusing tbh.

I would really appreciate some help with this, thanks a lot !

Comment: If your code works but needs improvements, then the right place is [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be to learn about the Class Based Views in Django. This will help reduce some of the boilerplate code you have to do all the time (if request.method == "POST", form.is_valid(), etc). The classes will also help organise your code. Here is a good resource to help with using Class Based Views: [Classy Class Based Views](https://ccbv.co.uk/)

Another suggestion would be to read [The Pragmatic Programmer](https://pragprog.com/book/tpp20/the-pragmatic-programmer-20th-anniversary-edition) by Andy Hunt and Dave Thomas. This really helps you think about planning your code and how to think of potential future changes etc. It also discusses the DRY principle (don't repeat yourself).

In terms of your code I would recommend splitting some logic up into smaller functions. You are also instantiating the `ReservationForm` before the POST and then instantiating it again inside the POST(duplicate code). You also have duplicate `if request.method == "GET":`.

This is also not really a question for here but for [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I have to disagree on CBVs "reducing the boilerplate". CBVs have real use cases when you have domain specific logic that needs to be extensible, but for most cases they only make the execution flow uselessly complicated compared to FBVs.

Comment: I find the opposite, the execution flow of FBVs are complicated. For example CBVs allows you to keep all your view specific logic in a single class instead of scattered throughout the file. When it comes to maintaining it you can see exactly what the view is doing without jumping between scattered functions and FBVs.


Using classes allow you to create very extensible logic by using Mixins. Also when maintaining the code in the future it is very clear what logic is custom in a CBV VS looking through the usual boilerplate code in a FBV.

Comment: "the execution flow of FBVs are complicated." => err, not really - unless we have a very different definition of "complicated", but at most it's a couple branches (request method, is the form valid) - and that's for form handling views (simple get views are even simpler).

Comment: "CBVs allows you to keep all your view specific logic in a single class instead of scattered throughout the file" => if you find yourself with your FBVs code "scattered throughout the file" then you're doing it wrong - it's one single function, and usually a rather short one.  CBVs execution flow, OTH, __IS__ "scattered throughout the fileS" (all the base classes and mixins).

Comment: " when maintaining the code in the future it is very clear what logic is custom in a CBV VS looking through the usual boilerplate code in a FBV" => the reality is actually the exact opposite. FBVs are self-contained so you get the whole execution flow immediatly readable, while with CBVs all parts are "scattered" between the different methods and you have to inspect the bases classes and mixins to understand where and when which method is called.